# LINQ to Entities - sorting on child collection with filter

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Given the following entities:

```
Question
 -string Title
 -ICollection<Tag> Tags

Tag
 -string Value
 -string TagType
```

How can I sort `Questions` by the `Value` of `Tags` of a given `TagType`? The problem here being that a `Question` can have many `Tags` of a given `TagType`. In the event of a `Question` having multiple `Tags` (which is mostly unusual in my scenario), I just care about the first `Tag`.

Here's an example data table output where TagTypes have their own columns:

```
Title (Question.Title) | Topic (TagType) | Module (TagType)
-----------------------------------------------------------
Question 1             | Algebra         | Maths
```

Given an `IQueryable<Question>`, what expression can I send to `Queryable.OrderBy(...)` to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @James for the suggestion but that didn't work. The solution is to use `Min` and `Max` for the field of the child collection to be ordered by:

```
if (sortDescending)
{
    expr = q => q.Tags
        .Where(t => t.TagType.Equals(sortByTagType, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Max(t => t.Value);
}
else
{
    expr = q => q.Tags
        .Where(t => t.TagType.Equals(sortByTagType, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Min(t => t.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Enumerable.OrderBy(x => x.Tags.Where(x => x.TagType == aTagType).First().Value);
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct. That would order by tag type rather than tag value. I want to order by the value of a tag with a given tag type. So more like `Queryable.OrderBy(x => x.Tags.First(t => t.TagType.Equals(sortByTagType)).Value)`. With that in mind, will the `.First` correctly translate to SQL?

Comment: Just seen your edit so ignore the first half of that comment. Will the `.First` correctly translate to SQL?

Comment: @Flem yeah sorry I re-read the question after I answered. Yeah `First` should be translate fine. Even if it doesn't, you should be able to do `ToList().First()`

Comment: `ToList` is no good as I need to ensure this happens completely at the database level. I don't want to evaluate the source query to order the records.

Comment: @flem `ToList` is a last-resort approach, `First` should work fine.

Comment: `First()` doesn't play nice.

Comment: @flem what exception are you getting?